# AngularJS $location.path() not working for returnUrl

Tags: angularjs

I have a SPA using AngularJS.  I've just added security/authentication and everything appears to work nicely except redirecting after login if a `returnUrl` exists in the query string.

I have code in my app which will redirect to my login route if no user is authenticated.  For example, if a user attempts to access `http://localhost:55841/#/group/15` (which requires authentication), it will redirect to the login route with the following URL:

`http://localhost:55841/#/login?returnUrl=%2Fgroup%2F15`

Here is my login method which should redirect to the returnUrl route if it exists upon successful login:

```
var login = function (credentials) {
    return $http.post(baseUrl + 'api/login', credentials).then(function (response) {
        //do stuff
        var returnUrl = $location.search().returnUrl;
        if (returnUrl) {
            $location.path(returnUrl);
            //$location.path('/group/15');
        }
        $location.path('/');
    });
};
```

When I debug the login method, the value of returnUrl is `/group/15` which is what I would expect, yet it navigates to the following URL:

`http://localhost:55841/#/?returnUrl=%2Fgroup%2F15`

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you want to reditect on some different url then you can use "$window.location.href = '/';" to redirect

but for routing redirection you can check with $location.path('/someNewPath');
$location.replace();

Comment: You need to unescape the returnUrl.  Try using the `decodeURIComponent()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Logical code error, check this solution and your branches.

```
var login = function (credentials) {
    return $http.post(baseUrl + 'api/login', credentials).then(function (response) {
        $rootScope.currentUser = response.data;
        $rootScope.$broadcast('currentUser', response.data);
        var returnUrl = $location.search().returnUrl;
        if (returnUrl) {
            console.log('Redirect to:' + returnUrl);
            $location.path(decodeURI(returnUrl)); // <- executed first, but not redirect directly.
            //$location.path('/group/15');
        } else { //else :)
           console.log('Redirect returnUrl not found. Directing to "/".');
           $location.path('/'); // <- only redirect if no returnUrl isset/true
       }
    }, function (response) {
        $rootScope.currentUser = null;
        $rootScope.$broadcast('currentUser', null);
        return $q.reject(response);
    });
};
```

Hint: You need to filter lot of URL in your "returnUrl". Think about a case where the last page was `/`. So its a endless loop.

Comment: Doh.  Thanks!  It looks like I also have to remove the returnUrl from the query string like this: `$location.path(returnUrl).search('returnUrl', null);`. This works though.  What is the point of decodeURI?  It appears to decode it properly.

Comment: Na, it will not decoded. URLs can be parsed as "encoded" into URI-Paths. Thats a normal behavior. -> http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeURI.asp & http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURI.asp

Comment: When I don't decode it, returnUrl equals `/group/15`.  What is an example of a returnUrl that would require decoding?

Comment: Yes, depeding on your pesitence. For example `$cookie` does save data urlEncoded into cookies. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookieStore to ensure correct data handling on that persistence.